# What does the -a unary operator check?

Tags: bash, test

I have just found a couple of examples using `[ -a some_dir ]` or `[ -a some_file ]` but can't find what the `-a` operator is for. It seems it should be described in the man page for `test`/`[` but there it is just as a comparison operator `[ $expr1 -a $expr2 ]`. It seems it simply returns true if a file or dir exists, no matter the type or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `bash` and some other shells, `-a` is a synonym for `-e` (true if file exists).

```
$ help test
...
      -a FILE        True if file exists.
...
      -e FILE        True if file exists.
```

This is non-standard and not supported in all shells, so you better don't rely on it.

Notice that the manpage of `test(1)` documents the external command (`/usr/bin/test`, `/usr/bin/[`, etc), not the shell built-in.

Comment: and `help` is a shell builtin command that provides help on shell builtin commands.

Comment: @XTian `help` is a _bash_ built-in command which provides _incomplete_ help on built-in commands ;-)

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between command and builtin. It is too often pointed out `test` and `[` are the same command residing in `/usr/bin`. So, what is used whilst I am really testing with `[`? :))

Comment: You're always using the shell built-in no matter if you call it as `[` or `test` (unless you disabled it with eg `enable -n [`).

Comment: btw, the external `test`/`[` from GNU coreutils (the `/usr/bin/test` in "desktop" linux) used to support the unary `-a`. It [no longer does](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=88c32fa68ee7057744bfb6d41f6e8eb68801306f)